# Natbib square brackets color

Tags: bibtex

When using Bibtex w/ Natbib and square brackets, does anyone know how to change the color of the square brackets?

Comment: just a random guess: `\bibpunct{\color{red}[}{\color{red}]}{,}{a}{}{;}` IF it works, the reference [sheet](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) explains each argument in the command.

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi `\color{red}[` doesn't limit the scope to the bracket. `\textcolor{red}{[}` does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\bibpunct` and `\textcolor`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{uvwxyz.bib}
@ARTICLE{example,
  author = {Felix Lindlar and Armin Zimmermann},
  title = {A code Generation Tool for Embedded Automotive Systems Based on Finite State Machines},
  journal = {IEEE International Conference on Industrial Informatics},
  year = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\bibpunct{\textcolor{red}{[}}{\textcolor{red}{]}}{,}{a}{}{;}

\begin{document}

\cite{example}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{uvwxyz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the above, this works:

```
\definecolor{bleu_cite}{RGB}{34,111,212} % pure blue: {0,0,128}, light blue:{80,135,208}
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,        
allcolors = black,  
citecolor=bleu_cite
]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{\textcolor{bleu_cite}{[}}{\textcolor{bleu_cite}{]}}{,}{a}{}{;}
```